# Need help understanding what this Haskell function does

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Not sure exactly what this does, or what to enter into the function to find a pattern in the outputs

```
f0 f id [] = id

f0 f id (x:xs) = f x (f0 f id xs)
```

Comment: It's best to give some context. What led you to ask this question? What did you consider before asking?

Answer (score 4):

`f` and `id` remain the same throughout each recursive call, so let’s simplify it a bit:

```
f0 [] = id
f0 (x:xs) = f x (f0 xs)
```

That means `f0 xs` could expand to:

```
f x1 (f x2 (f x3 id))
```

which kind of looks like `foldr`. That’s because it is `foldr`.

```
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1, 2, 3]
6
Prelude> f0 (+) 0 [1, 2, 3]
6
```

Answer (score 4):

All right.  Let’s walk through it.  This is a recursive function with a base case and a recursion step.  It’s named `f0` and has three arguments, `f`, `id` (which confusingly has the same name as a function in the Prelude), and `(x:xs)`.  Unfortunately, it has no type signature, but we can already tell that the third is some kind of list.  So its signature will be something like `f0 :: a -> b -> [c] -> d`

The base case is simple: if the third argument is an empty list, the function returns `id`, which therefore has the type the function returns.  So these two types are the same and we can refine the type signature to `f0 :: a -> b -> [c] -> b`.

The recursive case gets called only when the list `(x:xs)` is not empty.  It calls `f`, which therefore must be a function of two arguments, with `x` (the head of the list) as the first argument to `f`, and a call to `f0` as the second argument.  Since the return value of `f` is a valid return value of `f0`, they must have the same return type.  We can therefore deduce at this point that, if `b` is the return type of `f0` and `[a]` the type of the third argument, the signature of this function must be:

`f0 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

Now, let’s take a closer look at the second argument of `f` in the recursion step.  It calls `f0 f id xs`, which is the exact same call, but to the tail of the list.  (As a result, the list gets one element shorter with each step, until it’s empty and we reach the base case, so the algorithm must terminate.)  Therefore, `f0 (+) 0.0 [1,2,3]` expands to `1 + (2 + (3 + 0.0) )`.  This is a function from the Prelude; can you tell which?

**Edit:** The other answer spoiled it, but I’ll note that the names are hints, too.  `f0` and `f` are *functions*, `id` is short for *identity element* (because the intended model is that you add it to the last element of the list and get that same element back, the way that adding 3 + 0.0 gets you the floating-point number 3.0), and *x:xs* is the conventional way to refer to list arguments in recursive functions.

Comment: Clicked the review button for the first time, and guess which post came up?  Thanks for catching my typos.

Answer (score 0):

To decipher code I sometimes find it useful to exploit `Data.SimpleReflect` and run a few tests.

```
> import Debug.SimpleReflect
> let f0 f id [] = id ; f0 f id (x:xs) = f x (f0 f id xs)
> f0 f a [b,c,d,e]
f b (f c (f d (f e a)))
```

Looks familiar... is it `foldr`?

```
> foldr f a [b,c,d,e]
f b (f c (f d (f e a)))
```

OK, it is.